# Running Ruby on Rails from subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, subdomain

I must be missing something, but RoR is just not working for me at all.  I have RoR installed where I am hosting, and I have done all of the following:

```
cd ~
rails rubyonrails
ln -s rubyonrails www/rubyonrails/rails
```

Added to rubyonrails/public/.htaccess

```
RailsBaseURI /rubyonrails
```

Then:

```
cd rubyonrails
script/generate model User
script/generate controller User list
```

When I go to http://rubyonrails.truthanduntruth.com/rails/ it seems like it's just not running RoR at all.  This might have to do with the fact that I'm using the subdomain.  I set up the subdomain with cpanel, so I'm not sure how it's done.  The subdomain folder itself is in `/home/public_html/rubyonrails`

So you can also go to http://truthanduntruth.com/rubyonrails/rails/ .  Instead this gives me an error page.  This is no better.  Based on the error page or my steps above, can anyone tell what I am missing or where I am going wrong?

I'd like to at least get RoR running at all so I can learn it, but preferably I want it to run under the subdomain.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean subdirectory? That's what your instruction seem to hint at.

Comment: Yes, it is a subirectory, but the domain rubyonrails.truthanduntruth.com will also work.  The contents of the subdomain are stored in the subdirectory www/rubyonrails.  At any rate, ignoring that fact, it doesn't even work when treated like a normal directory anyway, but I want it to.

Comment: Do you want rubyonrails.truthanduntruth.com or truthanduntruth.com/rails? The configuration is different for each.

Comment: Have you started a ruby on rails server and setup the server to work on port 80, or are you just placing your files in the www directory?

Comment: I haven't set it up to work on port 80, but I don't know how to do that or even that I should.  Which files are in www?  The ruby files are in /home/user/rubyonrails and I have a symlink from /home/user/www/rails to /home/user/rubyonrails/public .  Seems to work if you go to the folder directly (not the subdomain version) but then I get some other error.  Check out the link above.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading a basic ruby on rails tutorial - especially chapters regarding deployment. I would also recommend testing this out all on a local machine first. It appears that you are going about setting up your server incorrectly. To get rails working you'll need to actually run a server that has access to port 80. Also, to run from a subdomain you'll need to either host your application on a different box that that subdomain points to, or configure apache to serve that subdomain with your ruby on rails server.

Comment: Which tutorial?  I've read about 7.  A lot of them start talking about setting up a DB before they even tell you how to access a page, which is no help.  I am running a server that I assume has access to port 80 since it does actually work fine with PHP, and it will display the RoR error page (though I could find no info from the error).  How could I configure apache to serve the subdomain with rails?